# Exclude variable from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a new website and want to make URLs SEO friendly.

My RewriteRule in .htaccess:

```
Working: RewriteRule ^news/design-watches/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ news_view.php?category=$1&title=$2&id=$3

Return: http://localhost/news/design-watches/Technical-Data/Test-News-9/37.html
```

Question:

Is it possible to hide ID from URL and still sending an variable $id to another website to $_GET informations from it?

```
Problem: RewriteRule ^news/design-watches/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ news_view.php?category=$1&title=$2&id=$3

Result: http://localhost/news/design-watches/Technical-Data/Test-News-9.html
```

I'd like to exclude the ID part from the URL, but I will have to have it to pass informations between the sites.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the URL does not contain a third capture pattern, then you can't use `$3` in the rewrite target. And if your URL does not contain an ID value, there's no way to get that information from the URL for use later on.

So I don't think you can achieve what you're hoping to achieve.